# How to escape special chars when sending mail via PHPmailer while keeping Polish characters?

Tags: php, regex, escaping, phpmailer

I'm making a simple contact form for a site, and I've come across a slight problem - when sending mail via PHPmailer, i can pass HTML tags, curly braces and other special characters in my form, **which probably isn't really a good idea...**

Problem is - I need to keep spaces and Polish characters (**ąćęłńóśźż**), and I'm an *absolute newbie* in regular expresions and php.

I resorted to using `preg_replace` doing basically this:

```
function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
}
```

As you might expect, that leaves me with this kind of garbage:

*Before preg_replace*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7u4J.jpg

*After preg_replace*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOzRK.jpg

All help is appreciated!

---

## Problem solved: Summary

Ended up following *Álvaro González's* suggestion of using the **[zendEscaper](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-05-16-zend-escaper.html)** component to escape HTML tags. Did so by doing this

```
$inputFieldName = $escaper->escapeHtml($_POST['inputFieldName']);
```

every time I need to make sure there can't be any HTML used, where `inputFieldName` is your `<input name="">` attribute.

---

If for some other reason you really need to do what I asked to do in the first place, which is removing some characters entirely, but leaving English and Polish letters, numbers and spaces, then *Toto's* answer suits your needs:

```
function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ\s-]/u', '', $string);
}
```

Again, thanks everyone for help!

Comment: What's wrong with Polish chars and HTML tags? Even if you app is not using UTF-8, you can configure PHPMailer to use whatever encoding you need. Your `clean()` function looks like a bad idea: you are just corrupting user input.

Comment: You're right, didn't think about that really... Maybe it's time to stop coding at 4 am :P I just wanted to get rid of HTML markup that would make XSS possible. Is it enough then if I instead use `strip_tags`?

Comment: You haven't really shared any code and I'm not sure of what problem you're trying to solve. If you're generating email in HTML format and you're injecting plain text then you need to [escape it properly](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-05-16-zend-escaper.html), rather than damage it.

Comment: Thank You! That was exacly what I was looking for but didn't really know how to phrase it correctly! I'm using ZendEscape now and it's just what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just add spaces and Polish characters inside the character class:

```
function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9ąćęłńóśźż\s-]/u', '', $string);
}
```

The `/u` flags is mandatory to deal with unicode characters.

Comment: You probably also need the `u` flag for this to be processed properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately Alvaro in the comments above showed me that it's really a bad practice to do what I tried to do and I ended up using zendEscape instead. Anyway, in case someone tries to reference this in some case, for your answer to be completely right it should include uppercase characters aswell, so `'/[^A-Za-z0-9ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ\s-]/u'`